# Jquery Issue creates flashing text and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery so that text fades in every time the user hovers their mouse over a thumbnail image/video. If the user slowly hovers over the item, the effect works fine and the text fades in and out over the images. However, if the user quickly moves the cursor around the screen over multiple images, the text flashes in the header of the website instead of within the image.

Here is a link to the website:
https://sulemankhalid.com/home.html

Example of HTML:

```
  <a href="animation.html">
        <div class="cell" id="animation">
          <div id="video-container" style="z-index: -1;">
            <video autoplay loop muted style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
              <source id="mp4" src="https://sulemankhalid.com/thumbnails/animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <h2>Animation &</h2>
            <h2>Motion Graphics</h2>
            <p>Shion Uino left Sushi Saito, a restaurant many consider to be one of the best in the world, to chart his own path in New York.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
```

Example of Jquery:

```
  $("#animation h2").hide();
        $("#animation p").hide();
        $("#animation").hover(function(){
          $("#animation h2").fadeIn(400);
          $("#animation p").fadeIn(400);
          $("#animation video").fadeTo("slow", 0.1);
        }, function(){
          $("#animation h2").fadeOut(400);
          $("#animation p").fadeOut(400);
          $("#animation video").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        });
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: instead of using javascript for these effects, it might be beneficial to you to investigate css3 transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing relative positioning on the parent to the absolutely positioned info.

In the CSS definition for `.cell`, add `position: relative;` like so:

```
.cell {
    background-color: #23384b;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 325px;
    height: 325px;
    margin: 1.72%;
    transition: 0.4s;
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

For reference, here's the CSS definition for `.info`

```
.info {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: That solved it!

Merak Marey's answer solved the flashing and Ted's answer solved the displaced text.

Comment: So maybe up voting our answers would not hurt..?

Answer (score 1):

If you head to the jQuery doc for hover (https://api.jquery.com/hover/) you will see on the first demo that they have the same "defect" you have on you page. This is not actually a defect, its a characteristic of jQuery. What you have to do is to stop the running animation before starting the next one. See https://api.jquery.com/stop/